# Covariance AR(2) Process

Tags: covariance, time

I am not sure what the formula is for the covariance of an AR(2) process, described by
$X_t - \mu = \phi_1(X_{t-1} - \mu) + \phi_2(X_{t-2}  -\mu ) + \epsilon_t$

where $\mu$ denoted the process mean and $\{ \epsilon_t\}$ a Gaussian white noise process with $\epsilon_t \sim (0,\sigma^2)$

What is the formula for $Cov(X_,X_{−})$ ?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/325137

Comment: This question has been answered here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265478/i-want-to-find-the-covariance-for-an-ar2-process

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Cross Validated and has been answered there.

Answer (score -2):

Use variance algebra to derive the variance or standard deviation of $X_t$ and $X_{t-j}$, as well as their correlation, then multiply these three quantities together to get the covariance between the two series